# Creating a start menu in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to create a start menu to my unity game when I found this script that enables a hidden sprite as soon as the game starts. The script then disables it when the player presses the left mouse button or space. When I try to make multiple sprites show up and the disappear, using the same script, only one sprite appears. I'm also trying to find a way to change the scipt so that the payer have to click on the actual sprite to disable it instead of just pressing the space key.

This is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class StartScreen : MonoBehaviour {

    static bool sawOnce = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if(!sawOnce) {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }

        sawOnce = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Time.timeScale==0 && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) ) {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds as if you are looking to do something like this: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Also, I always create a separate scene for my main menu systems, as they have done in that link.